# React: router does not refresh page if url is similar

Tags: reactjs

I have this app:

```
function App() {
  
const reload = () => {
  console.log()
}


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/table/metadata/" onClick={reload}>
            
            <button class="button" >
                <span>
                  Metadata
                </span>
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/table/spot/">
            <button class="button">
                <span>
                  SPOT
                </span>
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/table/activity/">
            <button class="button">
                <span>
                  Activity
                </span>
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/table/users/">
            <button class="button">
                <span>
                  Users
                </span>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <Routes>

          <Route path="/table/:name/" element={<SortingTable/>}></Route>
          <Route path="" exact element={<BasicTable/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I go from `localhost` to `localhost/table/any_table` the page shows the correct table. But if i try to go from any table to another, e.g. `localhost/table/activity` to `localhost/table/metadata`, then the page shows the activity table, while the url gets changed to `localhost/table/metadata`

The sorting table:

```
 
function SortingTable () {

    let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
    const { name } = useParams();

    useEffect(() =>{
        getData()
        getColumns()
    }, [])

    const getData = () => {
        getTable(name).then(result => {
            setData(result); // <-----
            console.log(result)
        })
    }

    const getColumns = () => {
        getColumnFields(name).then(result => {
            setColumns(result); // <-----
        })
    }
    
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: columns,
        data: data 
    },
    useSortBy)
    
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, footerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = tableInstance

    return (
        ...
    )

}

export default SortingTable
```

Is there a problem with the routing?

Comment: please add your SortingTable component to question

Comment: Could you include your routes setup? I suspect the cause lies within there somewhere.

Comment: Added the Sorting Table.

Comment: the routes are in App.js, otherwise I do not know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

long ago I stuck into this problem and I resolved this by giving `parameter key` to useEffect dependency array.

in your `SortingTable` component apply `name` to dependency array of useEffect

```
useEffect(() =>{
    getData()
    getColumns()
}, [name])
```